# virtualhost not working properly

Tags: apache, virtualhost

i set up 2 virual hosts:

### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:81  
NameVirtualHost *:82  
....  
<VirtualHost *:81>  
ServerName krmsrv05  
#    ServerAlias krmsrv05  
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"  

#    ServerAdmin postmaster@krmsrv05  
#    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"  
#    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:82>
    ServerName krmsrv05  
#    ServerAlias pprod.krmsrv05  
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portail_zf"  
#   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"  

   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/portail_zf">  
        DirectoryIndex index.php  
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

### httpd.conf

```
Listen 81  
Listen 82  
...  
ServerName krmsrv05
```

my problem is the second Vhost(port 82) works but the first one no :(
no error messages given by apache (...)

i need your help
many thanx :)
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Have you tried giving each VirtualHost a specific name? What happens with the first one, does the request time out?

Comment: the first virtualhost gives me a blank page, it seems that the virual host is available but returns nothing.
The funny is it already worked before with the same settings, I updated my server xampp, and the problem occurred: (
I can not give a different name for each virtual host, because my server is in a network controlled by a DNS server.

Comment: If you get a blank page, there is a strong indication that it is working. Try to find out from the server logs which resource is served

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but it may have something to do with your firewall. I've never personally used anything other that 80.  Unless you have a specific need that requires you to use different ports I would recommend you only use port 80 or 8080.  You have all of your virtual hosts using the same port you just have to use a different ServerName. Also make sure in your etc hosts file you add:

```
127.0.0.1    servername.com
```

Where servername.com is what you put next to ServerName in your vhost file. I recommend using a .com at the end of the servername otherwise I've found that browsers will treat your url request as if you're trying to search google.

I hope that helps. Let me know if I didn't understand your question or I didn't make myself clear :) Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your answer Chris:)
I work in a local network, port 80 on my server is occupied by another service, so I changed the port, the second virualhost (82) I use it to provide direct access to a particular project (project with Zend Framework), instead of "http://krmsrv05:81/portail_zf/public/" I use "http://krmsrv05:82/"

by the way "http://krmsrv05:81/portail_zf/public/" works correctly but no other page do.

Comment: to solve my problem, I did everything from the beginning, I removed everything and I reinstalled my server. thanks all for helping me, ti's very helpful  
:)